# Inset selection in gimp? Reverse drop-shadow?

Tags: iphone, graphics, gimp

I'm wondering how to achieve this effect that Apple uses. It looks as though the button is depressed into the bar, can't figure out how to do the same effect for my graphics.

Thanks!

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_i_vW6-bW2gE/S8VOyjmM3_I/AAAAAAAAAEA/OesJ5m0QQnc/s800/example.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_i_vW6-bW2gE/S8VOyjmM3_I/AAAAAAAAAEA/OesJ5m0QQnc/s800/example.png)

Comment: This is more of a software and design, rather than programming, question, so I'd argue that it belongs on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like more of a border with a fade effect on the button background, but you can use a [plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/186?page=1) that'll do an inner shadow.